# Qtilities: Custom property types for the property browsers?

Tags: c++, qt, qproperty

I'm writing a program that requires the user to be very flexible in manipulating data on a given object.  I figured I would use a property browser of some kind; Qtilities' [`ObjectDynamicPropertyBrowser`](http://jpnaude.github.io/Qtilities/class_qtilities_1_1_core_gui_1_1_object_dynamic_property_browser.html) caught my eye.

However, I need to be able to add my own data types.  The documentation is not clear on how to do so.

**How can I allow my own data types to be represented in Qtilities' property browser widgets?**

Also, more about my needs:

- The data types are not part of Qt, nor are they even `Q_OBJECT`s.
- Qt-specific modifications to the relevant classes are not an option.
- Declaring the relevant classes via `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` is okay.
- In particular, I need to represent vector and matrix types (and possibly more later).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser you refer to depends on the `QObject` property system. So, unless your classes are QObjects, it won't work - but don't despair, Qt 5.5 to the rescue (read on). The browser seems to use a `QTreeView` and provides an adapter model that exposes the `QObject` property system. So, it leverages Qt's type and delegate system.

In Qt 5.5, there is a general purpose property system, known as gadgets, that can be used on any class, as long as there is a `QMetaObject` describing that class. By adding the `Q_GADGET` macro to a class deriving from the subject class, and describing the properties using `Q_PROPERTY` macro, you can leverage `moc` and the gadget system to access your unmodified types' properties.

The only reason you'd do that is to require minimal changes to the `ObjectPropertyBrowser` system. You don't want the `ObjectDynamicPropertyBrowser`, since it works on dynamic properties, and your objects don't have any. They have static properties, given through `Q_PROPERTY` macros and code generated by moc.

So, you'll proceed as you would for implementing your own type support for `QVariant` and views in general. You also need Qt 5.5, since you need gadget support for it to work. A solution for Qt 5.4 and below requires a different approach and might be less cumbersome to implement in another way.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31950074/1329652) for a reference on using gadget property system for object serialization, it's fundamentally what the property browser would do, sans the serialization proper of course.

There are three steps. First, you need to address simple custom types that don't have a structure, but represent a single value (such as a date, or time, or geographic position, etc.), or a collection of simple values (such as a matrix).

1. Ensure that `QVariant` can carry the simple types. Add the `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` macro right after the type's definition in an interface (header file).
2. Implement [delegates for the types](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#delegate-classes). For types with table structure, such as a matrix, you can leverage `QTableView` and provide an adaptor model that exposes the type's contents as a table model.

Secondly, you get to your complex types that have internal structure:

1. Create a wrapper class that derives from the complex type, declares all properties using `Q_PROPERTY`, and has the `Q_GADGET` macro (not `Q_OBJECT` since they are not QObjects). Such class should not have any members of its own. Its only methods should be optional property accessors. The `Q_GADGET` macro adds the static (class) member `staticMetaObject`.
2. The underlying type can be `static_cast` to the wrapper class if needed, but that's normally not necessary.
3. At this point, any class that you wrote a wrapper for is accessible to the `QMetaProperty` system directly, without casting! You'd use the wrapper's `staticMetaObject` for its static metaobject, but the [`QMetaProperty`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaproperty.html) `readOnGadget` and `writeOnGadget` will take the pointers to the base class directly.

Thirdly, since `ObjectPropertyBrowser` most likely doesn't implement the support for gadgets in Qt 5.5, as that's quite new, you'll have to modify it to provide such support. The changes will be minimal and have to do with using `QMetaProperty::readOnGadget` and `QMetaProperty::writeOnGadget` instead of `QMetaProperty::read` and `QMetaProperty::write`. See the [serialization answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31950074/1329652) for comparison between the two.

Comment: Thank you very much!  A wrapper object would be more fitting in my case than a subclass, but I get the idea.

Comment: @JesseTG The wrapper class exists only so that *moc* can process the property declarations. You don't have to instantiate the wrapper - it only exists for its static `staticMetaObject` member. Wrapper objects will be more resource intensive, and don't give you any clear gains.